# Get the first match word in a text regex

Tags: regex

I need to find an item's information from a PO. I have the **item number**, **description**, **quantity**, **unit price**, **tax percentage**, and **total price**. I should find 3 matches, but item 3 has a big description information and breaks the text across several lines:

```
1 99999 Item description item description <DESC> 2 100.10 10% 200.20
2 99999 Item description item description <DESC> 3 100.10 10% 300.30
3 99999 Item description item description
Item description item description
Item description item description
 <DESC> 1 100.10 10% 100.10
```

I created the tag `<DESC>` to try to use as end point of description, because there are numbers and special characters in the description and I need to use `.*` to get it.

I created this regex to match the line, but it is not working, because of item 3. I'm using `{1,4}` here to get the big description:

```
\d{1,3}\s*\d{5}\s*\s*(.+\s*\n*){1,4}<DESC>\s*\d{1,3}\s*([0-9]+(\,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})\s*([0-9]+(\,[0-9]{1,2})?)\%\s*([0-9]+(\,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})
```

...but it generates only 2 matches.

```
1 99999 Item description item description <DESC> 2 100.10 10% 200.20
2 99999 Item description item description <DESC> 3 100.10 10% 300.30
```

and

```
3 99999 Item description item description
Item description item description
Item description item description
 <DESC> 1 100.10 10% 100.10
```

Is there a way to change `(.+\s*\n*){1,4}<DESC>` to get the first `<DESC>` and find 2 matches between items 1 and 2?

Comment: You seems to be able to modify the content, so you should better format it, instead of using a regex

Comment: Without a real example it's impossible for me to help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, regexp quantifiers are greedy, so they'll match the longest possible string that allows the rest of the regexp to match. Instead of `{1,4}`, use `+?` to get non-greedy matching of the description.